# What would be the diameter of this set?

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

Let, $t \in [0,1]$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Let, $f(t) = tx + (1-t)y$, such that, $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. What would $$\textrm{diam}(f([0,1])),$$
where $\textrm{diam}([a,b]) = \sup\{d(x,y):x,y \in [a,b] \}$ be? I think the answer is $f(1) - f(0)$, but I have no way of showing this.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your issue to answer the question? Do you know what the diameter is? Can you update the question with those points? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose without loss of generality that $x<y$ (I'm assuming $x\neq y$, otherwise $f$ is constant and $f([0,1])$ has diameter $0$).

If $s,t\in [0,1]$, then
$$
|f(s)-f(t)|=|(s-t)x+(t-s)y|=|s-t||x-y|\le |x-y|
$$
Thus $|x-y|$ is an upper bound of your set. Since this value is attained, namely at $0$ and $1$, then the diameter is $|x-y|$.

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck on proving something so simple, now I can complete my homework.Since this was a key result I wanted to use.